# Auto re-size div elements

Tags: html, css

I was wondering of some one can give me a hand on a little thing. I working on a personal project and can't get one thing of it correct.

Here is the JSBin http://jsbin.com/inixuf/1/edit

The problem is in images, if the screen is smaller then 21" and say is 15.3" it will only show 3 images per row while on 21" it will show 4 images per row and as you get bigger it will show more and more. This is not what I wan't I want a script that can force re-size the image div class in order to assure that no matter what's you're screen you will always be getting 4 images per row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use % to set the widths.

So an image is width:20% of div width, with a margin of 2.5% on each side of the image. That way you fill up the 100% nicely.

.imagecontainer {
width: 20%;
margin-left:2.5%;
margin-right:2.5%;
}

and then have all sizes be relative

Comment: I know I had to wait sorry :) as I am a new user

Comment: No worries ;-) I know you're new but that's why I pointed it out. A lot of new users simply "forget" do do such a little favor ;-) Thank you.